# HTTPS Security IE nokia maps

Tags: security, internet-explorer, maps, here-api

I'm using nokia maps in my html page by including this script (with https)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.4/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
```

If I access my site using https then it gives me the security warning message :

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://1.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile....
```

How can i force the scripts to get the maps with https ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a configuration issue. In order to fix it you have to add this line in your nokia here declaration :

nokia.Settings.set("secureConnection", "force");

Comment: I´ve got exactly that implementation in version 2.5.3.? Is it working for you in that version?